# How can MapStruct be used to simplify mapping of complex DTO layers in a Spring application?

Tags: java, spring, mapstruct

How to use MapStruct to map multi-layer DTO:

```java
// Menu.java
public class Menu {
    private String path;
    private String name;
    private String component;
    private String redirect;
    private MenuMeta meta; // <- This 
}
```

```java
// MenuMata.java
public class MenuMeta {
    private String title;
    private String icon;
    private Boolean hideMenu;
    private String currentActiveMenu;
    private Boolean ignoreKeepAlive;
    private Boolean showMenu;
    private String frameSrc;
    private Boolean hideBreadcrumb;
}
```

```java
// MenuSaveQuery
public class MenuSaveQuery {
    private Long parentId;
    private String path;
    private String name;
    private String component;
    private String redirect;
    private String title;
    private String icon;
    private Boolean hideMenu;
    private String currentActiveMenu;
    private Boolean ignoreKeepAlive;
    private Boolean showMenu;
    private String frameSrc;
    private Boolean hideBreadcrumb;
}
```

I want to project the above two classes into this one below, but I don't know how to do it.

Like this:

```java
public Menu save(MenuSaveQuery query);
```

I know that I can use @Mapping `target` and `source` to map one by one, but this is too much trouble. Is there any easy way

Comment: Write it yourself in a dedicated method or use `@Mapping` which will generate the proper code.

Comment: Alternatively you could write two mappers that take `Menu&MenuSaveQuery` and `MenuMeta&MenuSaveQuery ` as existing Objects and you map only the respective properties of that one Object, ignoring the rest for each mapper.

Answer (score 0):

There is a solution for that, according to Mapstruct document: https://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/pdf/mapstruct-reference-guide.pdf

> If you don’t want explicitly name all properties from nested source bean, you can use . as target.

```
@Mapper
public interface CustomerMapper {
    @Mapping( target = "name", source = "record.name" )
    @Mapping( target = ".", source = "record" )
    @Mapping( target = ".", source = "account" )
 Customer customerDtoToCustomer(CustomerDto customerDto);
}
```

The generated code will map every property from CustomerDto.record to Customer directly, without
need to manually name any of them. The same goes for Customer.account.